# Extracts all characters before the 3rd occurrence of a delimiter in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2014

For example the string is `AL*12345*B001*1`

Please help me get the result to be `AL*12345*B001` (all characters before the third '*' delimiter. Below I'm using a reverse to look for the last delimiter and then get all characters to the left.

```
DECLARE @properID VARCHAR(50)
SET @properID = 'AL*12345*B001*1'
SELECT LEFT(@properID, CHARINDEX ('*',REVERSE(@properID))-1)
```

The result of this query is A

Answer (score 2):

Here is the description of LEFT function:
"Returns the left part of a character string with the specified number of characters."

You need to compute the number of characters to get from the left.

Try this:

> select left(@properID,len(@properID)-CHARINDEX('*',reverse(@properID)))

Answer (score 0):

See attached SQLFiddler: [SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73c35/1/0)

```
DECLARE @properID VARCHAR(50)
SET @properID = 'AL*12345*B001*1'

;WITH CTE_REC AS 
 (
  SELECT 1 as R ,CHARINDEX('*', @properID) as Pos , @properID ProperId
   UNION ALL
  SELECT R + 1 , CHARINDEX ('*' ,@properID , Pos + 1) , ProperId
   FROM CTE_REC
   WHERE Pos > 0 

 )
 SELECT ProperId, 
  SUBSTRING(ProperId , 0 , Pos) RequiredProperId
  FROM CTE_REC
  WHERE Pos > 0 
  AND R = 3 --Change this condition accordingly if you need only until nth occurance
```